# apache-arrow: How to create an empty table based on schema using the javascript API?

Tags: apache-arrow

I'm trying to build a new empty Table based on schema only using the javascript API.
I have tried different approaches unsuccessfully. I can't find in the documentation either

```
import {Schema, Field, Table} from '../node_modules/apache-arrow/Arrow.dom'
import {Type} from '../node_modules/apache-arrow/fb/Schema'

const field1 = Field.new('field1',Type.FloatingPoint);
const field2 = Field.new('field2',Type.Int);

const schema = new Schema([field1, field2]);

const table = Table.empty(schema)

console.log(table)
```

From the browser (firefox) I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Unrecognized typeId undefined
new webpack://wstat/./node_modules/apache-arrow/data.js?:152
_InternalEmptyPlaceholderRecordBatch webpack://wstat/./node_modules/apache-arrow/recordbatch.js?:94
_InternalEmptyPlaceholderRecordBatch webpack://wstat/./node_modules/apache-arrow/recordbatch.js?:94
Table webpack://wstat/./node_modules/apache-arrow/table.js?:42
empty webpack://wstat/./node_modules/apache-arrow/table.js?:48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution below:

```
const field1 = Field.new({name:'field1',type:new Float(Precision.DOUBLE)})
const field2 = Field.new({name:'field2',type:new Int(true,64)})

const tab2 = Table.empty(new Schema([field1,field2]))
```

The difference is the field constructor type argument. Should be a class Type and not the enum Type.